# Sitecore Best practice for setting up standard values

Tags: sitecore

I've seen various implementation of standard values.  Some I've seen only has layout configured and others with full renderings.

I think it's best to configure layout, renderings , $name, icons etc.

Does anyone have any recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Important Standard Values

To minimize administration and maximize consistency, I recommend that, whenever possible, you define the following types of values in standard values for data templates rather than in individual items:

Layout Details: In standard values for a data template, specify presentation components and rendering rules to apply to the item for various devices
Insert Options: In standard values for a data template, control the types of items that users can insert beneath items associated with that data template
Initial Workflow: In standard values for a data template, specifies the default publishing workflow for items of that type

You can find more here about standard values: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/all-about-standard-values-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx
If you want to extend standard values functionality please check here: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/add-custom-standard-values-tokens-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx